# JavaScript: Merge multiple Arrays object in to single Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge

I am receiving the following data in the variable

```
let data = [
    [{option: “foo0", value: “bar0”}],
    [{option: “foo1", value: “bar1”}],
    [{option: “foo2", value: “bar2”}],
    [{option: “foo3", value: “bar3”}],
 ]
```

and I need to change the response to

```
[
    {option: “foo0", value: “bar0”},
    {option: “foo1", value: “bar1”},
    {option: “foo2", value: “bar2”},
    {option: “foo3", value: “bar3”},
]
```

how can i do it in JS

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: `data.map(item => item[0])`

Comment: This is achievable with [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Methods_2) methods. What have you tried?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well I don't think this is a bad question at all (basic – maybe). I also don't think everybody must/is able to do a research before asking a question. So I don't see a problem in thousands of duplicates of basic map question.

Comment: let extractObj = [];

data.map(function(arrOfObj){
 let insideDailyArr=arrOfObj.length;
 for(var i=0;i<insideDailyArr;i++){
  extractObj.push(arrOfObj[i])
 }
}); /*your result will be in extractObj*/

Answer (score 6):

Use `Array.flat()`:

```js
const data = [[{"option":"foo0","value":"bar0"}],[{"option":"foo1","value":"bar1"}],[{"option":"foo2","value":"bar2"}],[{"option":"foo3","value":"bar3"}]]

const result = data.flat()

console.log(result)
```

If `Array.flat()` is not supported, you can flatten the array by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) into [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const data = [[{"option":"foo0","value":"bar0"}],[{"option":"foo1","value":"bar1"}],[{"option":"foo2","value":"bar2"}],[{"option":"foo3","value":"bar3"}]]

const result = [].concat(...data)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Nice, non-canonical solution!

Comment: your idea is distinct,vote up!

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```js
let data = [
  [{
    option: "foo0",
    value: "bar0"
  }],
  [{
    option: "foo1",
    value: "bar1"
  }],
  [{
    option: "foo2",
    value: "bar2"
  }],
  [{
    option: "foo3",
    value: "bar3"
  }],
];

let result = data.map(v => v[0]);

console.log(result);
```